# How can I allow a Group to assume a Role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, identity-management

How can I allow all members of a Group to assume a Role in AWS IAM?

I tried Using the following statement but as specified in [AWS IAM Principal Element](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Principal), a Group can not be a Principal.

I want to achieve something like below:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::***:group/developer"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

The idea is that all members of the group `group/developer` should be able to assume the role. The objective is that I should be saved from having to specify each member in a group individually.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What role do you want them to assume? Can you provide a sample ARN?

Comment: The role is named developer as-well: so the ARN would be something like `arn:aws:iam::***:role/developer`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**Attach a policy to the Group** that grants permission to call `sts:AssumeRole` on the desired Role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/desired-role"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, attach a **Trust Policy on the Role**. The sample policy (below) trusts any user in the account, but they would also need `sts:AssumeRole` permissions (above) to assume the role.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: that's the way to do, but the trust policy trusts all users in the account, not specifically the ones in the IAM group. This is only controlled by the resource level of the policy, but I think Floo0 wants to specify "only the users in the group" in the trust relationship, which is not possible :(

Comment: @John Rotenstein, thanks for the solution (+1). After digging some deeper i found this solution as well. As Tom points our this solution "disables" the double-security for assuming roles. Especially for Cross-Account Role-Assuming i think this is a bit "risky"...

Comment: You will have to change the principal to use the ARN of the group. I guess he just copied an example with `:root` user allowed.

Comment: @kgpdeveloper Incorrect; as stated in the question, groups are *not* valid principals for IAM policies.

Comment: @John Rotenstein, thanks for the solution (+1). We are now using AWS STS Based on your recomendation.

Comment: Hey Josh, I'm having trouble getting this to work and asked in a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64761634/1366033) if you kindly have a moment to provide some clarity

Answer (score 21):

You cannot specify IAM groups as principals.

You specify a principal using the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the AWS account, IAM user, IAM role, federated user, or assumed-role user. You cannot specify IAM groups as principals.

Per the documentation in AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html

Comment: What's puzzling is the [docs for assume-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_permissions-to-switch.html) mention "it is best practice not to grant permissions directly to an individual user. For easier management, we recommend assigning policies and granting permissions to IAM groups and then making the users members of the appropriate groups." But it isn't actually possible to follow their guidance?

Comment: Longstanding [issue in the AWS discussion forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=356199#356199).

Answer (score 12):

As of December 2018 (no idea if they were correct at the time of writing) some statements expressed above about the limitations to groups sound misleading.

I'd like to add/clarify the accepted answer:

1) trusting `sts:AssumeRole` to `..:root` user **only POTENTIALLY** allows any user to assume the role in question. Unless you also grant the permission to some user or group to assume the role, it will not be allowed.

2) if you, like me, cannot have the permissions specified in the group definition because of resources living in different stacks and/or circular dependencies, the code to define a policy associated with a group is:

```
DevelopersAccess:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
    Groups:
        - !ImportValue another-stack-DevelopersGroupNameNotArn
    PolicyName: DevelopersAccess
    PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
            Resource:
            - arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/desired-role
```

Note that under `Groups` you have to list group names, not ARNs.

Comment: Thank you for further clarification. From that answer, I understood that "root" was the name of the group, this is explanation should be added to the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done in a different way. But, not sure whether this is what you want.
1) Create a policy using [create-policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/create-policy.html). 
2) Attach the policy to the `arn:aws:iam::***:role/developer` role using [attach-role-policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/attach-role-policy.html).
3) Create the intended `Group` using [create-group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/create-group.html).
4) Attach the specified managed policy to the specified Group using [attach-group-policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/attach-group-policy.html).

Same can be achieved through AWS console or AWS SDK instead of using CLI. Please see [Attaching a Policy to an IAM Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_groups_manage_attach-policy.html)

This way, you don't have to add the roles individually to each member in the group.

Comment: This solution is not what the original question is asking. it does not handle assuming a role at all and just grants the permission to the original group.