# AWS access to S3 bucket's folder for user groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I understand that in AWS we can control access to AWS S3 bucket as well as to contained folders for each user by using *username* variable in the bucket IAM policy. I followed this blog:
[Writing IAM Policies: Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Buckete](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

The question is that I do not see how this can be possible also for groups. Because I want to create folders **for groups** rather than folders for users. According to this [IAM Policy Elements: Variables and Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-infotouse) I understand that there is NO variable *group* that I can use in the policy.

Any idea? thanks

Comment: Try something like  "Principal": {
            "AWS": "UserGroupArn"
         }

Comment: @thatguy IAM group **can't** be principle in any policy, unfortunately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922920/how-can-i-allow-a-group-to-assume-a-role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this would be possible because an IAM User an be in multiple IAM Groups, so the name of the folder would not be predictable.

Instead, you would need to add a policy *to each group* that grants access to a specific bucket + path.

Comment: ok I think the same limitation applies if I leverage IAM Roles, right? I think your suggestion is the one, I am going to try it. thanks.